# Not passing through instance methods

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to do a app, but unfortunately it is not passing through all (void) instance methods (i copied the methods from another project)....
and also not showing any error....Can any one tell me know whats going wrong?????
I am building a app which has textfeild with drop down table

These are the methods:

```
- (void)finishedSearching;
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField ;
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string ;

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView ;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section ;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Kindly suggest

Comment: is this the .h or the .m file?

Comment: make sure your textfield and tableview ' delegate is set

Comment: @janusfidel: how to set the delegate if i create uitabel and UItext field programatically

Comment: @pradeepj Instead of just copying code, perhaps you should learn what it actually does and how it works so you can know how to fix things like this? And just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't really help us out in trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the delegate properly you need to do followingthings -

1. confirm to delegate protocol. For e.g. -

   `YourClass: SomeClass <UITextFieldDelegate>` -> this is delegate confirmation
2. Set the delegate, where you are creating control. For e.g. -

   `UItextField *myTextField = [[UItextField alloc] init];`
   `----`
   `myTextField.delegate = self;`
3. Now you need to provide the definition of required method of that delegate in your class.

Hope this clears.

Comment: one thing i create table using code how to set delegate to that tabel

Comment: you just need to add 1 line of code - table.delegate = self; also in .h file you need to have <UITableViewDelegate> ; then you need to implement the required delegate method of table view.

Comment: its not even printing -(void)print{NSLog(@"a");}

Comment: you need to show some more code, you can add your .h and .m files.

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
@interface YourClasss
YourClass : ParentClass < UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource >
@end
```

.m

```
 yourTableView.delegate = self;
 yourTableView.dataSource = self;
 yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

in your  .h file

```
@interface Class
Class : NSObject < UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource >
@end
```

in your .m file

```
viewDidLoad
{

 tblViewVar.delegate = self;
 tblViewVar.dataSource = self;
 tblViewVar.delegate = self

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```